# jInitiator console message infinite loop

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, windows-ias-server, oracle-application-server

we have this thick client application running on Oracle forms, using *Oracle Application Server version 10.1.2.0.2* and the client side uses *Oracle JInitiator: Version 1.3.1.22*
on some of the machines, we find the jinitiator console dumping thousands of lines similar to these:

```
@@@@@@@@ ValorLabel: Logon


@@@@@@@@ ToolTipAdded: 1: Position 1


@@@@@@@@ ToolTipAdded: 2: Position 2


@@@@@@@@ ToolTipAdded: 3: Position 3


######## ValorButton4: Connect pos: 4


@@@@@@@@ ValorLabel: Logon


@@@@@@@@ ToolTipAdded: 1: Position 1


@@@@@@@@ ToolTipAdded: 2: Position 2


@@@@@@@@ ToolTipAdded: 3: Position 3
```

and so on, I searched all over the web, with the application vendor, with Oracle meta link and with microsoft knowledge base but with no luck.

the problem of such repeated message, is that it correlates with high heap memory consumption and slow performance of the application that ends eventually by a crash or a hang.

I hope someone can help us identifying the origin of such dump message

**system specifications:**

- Client PC is a Windows XP Service Pack 3
- Browsers used IE 6 and IE 7
- jInitator version 1.3.1.22
- Server App Server is AIX 5.3 running Oracle Forms over Oracle App Server (ias) version 10.1.2.0.2 connected to a Database Server on a different box

we are planning to migrate to Sun Java Plug-in soon, but until we go through change management and testing, we need to find a reason behind this problem

**update**
this problem does not happen to my laptop, which is having the same jinitiator version.
the only difference I can see is the availability of different JREs and JDKs since I have eclipse installed on this machine..

However, the JRE used by jinitator in both cases (my latop and the affected PCs) is the exact same one.

```
Oracle JInitiator: Version 1.3.1.22
Using JRE version 1.3.1.22-internal Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
```

I did a dump system properties on the console and the result was almost the same between both terminals (good one and bad one) except for the user name. and some extra paths

thanks a million for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!!!

the reason turned out to be some conflict between the JInitiator installed and another application that was installed later on the same machines.
Lotus Expeditor which we pushed centrally seems to conflict with JInitiator causing this endless loop of comments dumped into the Java Console.
this sort of makes since now, since JInitator uses Java Virtual Machines to run, meanwhile, Lotus Expeditor is based on eclipse technology, which in turn is based on Java.
we managed to re-produce the same problem on a clean machine that had no problems before.

the solution to make JInitiator work correctly (regardless what would the impact on Expeditor would be) is to do as follows:

1. Un-install JInitiator
2. Delete the JInitiator directory (usually C:\Program Files\Oracle\JInitiator 1.3.x.x)
3. Remove all JInitiator related entries in register (using regedit)
4. Delete JAR files cache
5. Delete a file under user direcotry called .jinit
6. Reboot machine
7. Visit the site calling JInitiator, this will automatically load JInitiator on your machine
8. when asked, install JInitiator in a different directory

the problem should disappear here

note that for us to manage implementing steps 1 to 8, we needed local admin rights for the same user we logged on with on windows

Mysteries to answer are:

1. what caused the conflict between Expeditor and JInitiator?
2. will re-installing JInitiator conflict with the newly Lotus Expeditor?